# Why doesn't this simple datetime.combine operation work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to add time interval (of datetime.time type ) of 4 seconds to the curr_time (whic is datetime.datetime) as shown below.

At the end of the code snippet I would expect the final time to be up by 12 seconds. Why is it only incremented by 4?
(python version 3.5.1)

Would appreciate a second pair of eyes. Thanks.

```
import datetime

curr_time = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)

interval = datetime.time(0,0,4)

temp_time = datetime.datetime.combine(curr_time, interval)

other = datetime.datetime.combine(temp_time, interval)

final = datetime.datetime.combine(other, interval)

print('final ', final)
```

Comment: As an aside its usual to import `datetime` like `from datetime import datetime` to avoid the need to uses `datetime.datetime` all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more easily expressed with datetime.timedelta:

```
import datetime as dt

curr_time = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
interval = dt.timedelta(seconds=4)

temp_time = curr_time + interval
other = temp_time + interval
final = other + interval

print('final ', final)
```